# Puropse of train while loading a function from other file?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a piece of code in which they are calling following function in the training loop. Where next_batch  is a function stored in other file named sample. InputData is variable that is loading all training and test set labels and samples. I want to know that what is the purpose of train in InputData.train.next_batch?

```
`InputData 
=input_MC_Samples.read_data_sets('InputData',FLAGS.num_classes,one_hot=True)
for i in range(FLAGS.total_train_step):
    batch = InputData.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)`
```